# Browser document mode issues

Tags: internet-explorer, dojo, ie8-compatibility-mode

We have developed an application using dojo and it is working fine in ie8 and FF. But during the testing as some of the testers are having their IE8 document mode set defaulting to IE7 standards the UI and some functionality of our application is not working properly. We tried to change the document mode programatically using the meta tag as below but it seems not working.. can any one help to resolve this browser compatibility issue.. programatically.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```